# single searchbar filter items in multiple tabs in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic2, filtering

I am trying to have a single searchbar filter lists in 2 different tabs in ionic 2. I have the searchbar, and I have a method of filtering through the objects, but I want to be able to have different tabs for the user to select what they want to search for. Example..
"Search Page" has the ion-searchbar in it and the ion-tabs in it, with 2 tabs (People and blogs). When the user inputs content into the search bar it would filter the results in the active tab. So when you first go to the search page it would default to people, but then you can click the blogs tab to switch to searching blogs. I would like to have a single searchbar in the main search page.

Here is what I have currently..

SearchPage html...

```
<ion-header text-center>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Search Page</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
<ion-header>

<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" [formControl]="searchControl" (ionInput)="onSearchInput()"></ion-searchbar>
<div *ngIf="searching" class="spinner-container">
  <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
</div>

<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab tabIcon="people" [root]="peopleSearch"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="pricetags" [root]="postsSearch"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

That way I have the search bar in the main place so it doesn't have to refresh or redraw when switching between tabs. I can't figure out though, how to get access to it and it's value, as well as the ionInput event on both of the tab pages. I can only seem to use it on the main page.

I can post up all of my TS code that I have thusfar, for filtering the items and such, I am getting it all from a tutorial [Here](https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/)
I was thinking something with @ViewChild, but I am not good enough at ionic to figure out how to get that on both tabs pages and have all the events adn everything automatically work on both tabbed pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll present two ways, one very simple, one more correct.

1) `navCtrl.parent.getActive().instance.searchTerm`

The parent nav of your current nav are the tabs. The view Controller of that is getActive() and the instance is the actual instance of the class and so you have the data.

```
this.tabsInstance = navCtrl.parent.getActive().instance;

data | filter: searchTerm
```

2) The second option is to use EventEmitters. I think its most clean way and there is more separation between classes.

Create an EventEmitter in the tabs class

```
public searchEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Stick it on your root params

```
  <ion-tab [rootParams]="searchEmitter" tabIcon="people" [root]="peopleSearch"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [rootParams]="searchEmitter" tabIcon="pricetags" [root]="postsSearch"></ion-tab>
```

In each class take the navParams and assign it to the searchTerm.

```
public searchTerm:string;

constructor(navParams:NavParams){
      if(navParams)
      navParams.data.subscribe(searchTerm => this.searchTerm = searchTerm);
}
```

Emit the changes in the tabs when the searchInput changes

```
this.searchEmitter.emit(this.searchTerm);
```

The second answe might be longer but its certainly more correct.

Comment: Oh my, that is absolutely beautiful! Thank you so much! One quick question, when  do EventEmitter my IDE pops up import options "@angular/core", "PouchDB", "NodeJS", and `"events".internal`. I tried using the "@angular/core" one, but it tells me the signature requires one argument to be passed in.

Comment: The import is from @angular/core. The signature missing argument may refer to the missing generics. I also forgot to mention that you need to emit from tabs down so I'll edit that.